# Converting Invoke-WmiMethod command to Invoke-CimMethod command

Tags: powershell, sccm

I can't seem to reconfigure the below Invoke-WmiMethod command into a working Invoke-CimMethod command.  This code is used to run SCCM client actions.  An example of wanting to run the 'ApplicationDeploymentEvaluation' action is below.

What works:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace ROOT\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT -Name TriggerSchedule '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000121}'
```

My attempt to reconfigure into an easier to read and replicate CimMethod, which does not work.

```
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace ROOT\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT -Name TriggerSchedule '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000121}'
```

Error Received:

```
Invoke-CimMethod : Cannot bind parameter 'Arguments'. Cannot convert the "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000121}" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:106
+ ... CLIENT -Name TriggerSchedule '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000121}'
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-CimMethod], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand
```

I am fairly certain the issue has to do with the `-Name` but everything I've attempted to change it to has generated an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arguments` is a dictionary

> [[-Arguments] IDictionary]

```
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace ROOT\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT -Name TriggerSchedule -Arguments @{sScheduleID = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000121}'}
```

`sScheduleID` comes from

```
(Get-CimClass -Namespace ROOT\ccm -Class SMS_CLIENT).CimClassMethods
```